# D3.js update dom element text on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Please see [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Fallenstedt/pen/oBaamd?editors=1010) for what I am working on.

When I click on the legend (top left), I would like the data set to be displayed under the graph I made with C3.js

Currently, data is appended to the DOM with `p` elements when you click any legend item. The problem is that the text in these elements are not cleared and updated when you click a different legend item. The code that accomplishes this is lines 55-61

```
    .on('click', function (id) {
    chart.data(id)[0].values.map( obj => console.log(obj.value))
    d3.select('#values').selectAll("p")
      .data(chart.data(id)[0].values)
      .enter()
      .append('p')
      .text(function(d) { return d.value })
```

How can I have D3 clear the values in `#values` and update with new data when I click on a legend item? I was expecting d3 to just update the values automatically, but it only display the first dataset that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved your issue.  Just remove the elements each time prior to adding them. Here's the meat of the click method:

```
chart.data(id)[0].values.map( obj => console.log(obj.value))
    d3.selectAll('.legend_values')
      .remove();
    d3.select('#values').selectAll("p")
      .data(chart.data(id)[0].values)
      .enter()
      .append('p')
      .text(function(d) { return d.value })
      .classed('legend_values', true);
```

https://codepen.io/deweyredman/pen/RKeOJp?editors=1010

Now, the explanation as to why what you had did not work.  On the click method, you used "enter".  What's going on with that is whenever there aren't elements in the DOM to match the bound data, the code after enter is executed.  Since there are always the same number of p elements corresponding to elements in the dataset after you click once, the enter code isn't doing anything.  Now, if there were any additional elements, the enter method would catch them, and you'd see a change there... let me show you [in this codepen.](https://codepen.io/deweyredman/pen/ggByyo?editors=1010)

I updated the data source in your codepen to grow by one for each dataset.  Try clicking data1, data2, data3...etc.  You'll see that each time, since a new element is needed in the dom because the dataset grows by one each time, the p element is added corresponding to the CURRENT dataset.  Notice that when you go backwards, the elements don't go away.  This is where exit comes in...I'm going to make [another codepen](https://codepen.io/deweyredman/pen/MJPdag?editors=1010) to illustrate this concept:

In this codepen, you'll see that I'm using "exit" to remove any additional dom elements that aren't present in the current data set.  This, however assumes that the rest of the data is the same.

My [final codepen](https://codepen.io/deweyredman/pen/KaGLwY?editors=1010) illustrates where I use the exit technique to reset the data to nil every time before binding it to the p elements that are being appended.  This pen actually achieves the same thing as my original one.  The only difference here is that I'm explicitly unbinding and binding the data and in my original one, I'm just nuking the p elements so that the enter method fires each time.

Please let me know if any of this is unclear or doesn't make any sense to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense to target these values with a class so I can use `.remove()`. I was doing something similar with `.remove()` but was having issues.

Comment: Please read my explanation above, as it will help you understand why what you had didn't work. Cheers!

Comment: Your explanation is very clear. The behavior of `enter()` makes a lot more sense now. I'm a bit new to d3, but your explanation really cleared up a lot of my confusion. Thank you :).

Comment: Good to hear. I updated it once more to explain "exit".  Enter and exit are usually very powerful when you have a lot of dynamic data.  If you have any questions feel free to leave them here.